# AWS ElasticSearch/OpenSearch not connecting from java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Im using a simple example from amazon aws site to connect to opensearch index.
This is the example source  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-java.
The health status of my node is yellow and its open

yellow open   my-index

The error message

````
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:943)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1256)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1231)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:587)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.AWSElasticsearchServiceClient.main(AWSElasticsearchServiceClient.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ```
````

````
    private static String region = "us-west-1";
    private static String domainEndpoint = "<my-index...amazon.com>"; // e.g. https://search-mydomain.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com
    private static String index = "my-index";
    private static String type = "_doc";
    private static String id = "1";
    static final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

 ```   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RestHighLevelClient searchClient = searchClient(serviceName, region);

        // Create the document as a hash map
        Map<String, Object> document = new HashMap<>();
        document.put("title", "Walk the Line");
        document.put("director", "James Mangold");
        document.put("year", "2005");

        // Form the indexing request, send it, and print the response
        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(index, type, id).source(document);
        IndexResponse response = searchClient.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    // Adds the interceptor to the OpenSearch REST client
    public static RestHighLevelClient searchClient(String serviceName, String region) {
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
        signer.setRegionName(region);
        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, credentialsProvider);
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(domainEndpoint)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)));
    }
````

Comment: I hope the endpoint is not "<my-index...amazon.com>". It should be the endpoint of your opensearch domain which can be found in "general information" in opensearch dashboard in aws.

Comment: You are right, I dont want to put my endpoint here

Comment: @user8576589, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this example](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java-rest-high-level/). I tried the same and it did work well for me. I did not bother doing anything in regards to the cert as I had followed AWS demo examples to create the domain.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for...